# Facing an issue while converting HTML Div to pdf using Dom-to-image and JSPDF in safari browser

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, jspdf

I have coded a method to convert the HTML div to pdf using dom-to-image and jspdf. It is working fine with chrome browser, but in safari it is throwing an security error. Is there any way to achieve this is safari browser?

```
downloadPage(id, cbtNo, xAxis, docWidth, docHeight) {
    const self = this;
    co(this, function* () {
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      const parentNode = document.getElementById(id);
      domtoimage.toPng(parentNode, {
        filter: function (node) {
          if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.tagName === "INPUT" &&
            ("" + node.type).toLowerCase() === "checkbox") {
            if (node.checked) {
              node.setAttribute('checked', true);
            } else {
              node.removeAttribute('checked');
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
      })
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = dataUrl;
          doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', xAxis, 2, docWidth, docHeight);
          doc.save('file.pdf');
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          notifications.action('error').post({ msg: 'Error in exporting as PDF', title: 'Error' });
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi Prasanth, why don't you post the code you've tried so far, so we can have a starting point to answer your question?

Comment: Hi Alvin, I have added the code.

Comment: Can you post the security error?  Safari deals with pdf displaying and downloading a little differently than the other browsers.